# HiDPI Scaling Issues

Tags: hidpi

Recently I've had to go back to Windows for a few reasons.

1. being, I wanted to play FF XII the zodiac age; which simply wasn't installing on elementary OS steam.  Steam stated it is not available for my platform.
2. Using my work's citrix server to get only network from home was just not seamless.  the latest citrix didn't work and would immediately close upon opening, the older citrix worked, but it just wasn't the same.
3. HiDPI scaling really isn't so good on linux.  Elementary OS allows lowdpi which really isn't low dpi but allows native scaling.  It also has HiDPI, which is 2x scaling.  For me 2x scaling is atrocious.  Low scaling is too small.  On Windows I use 150% scaling.  I could get by on 125% as well; but pure 100 is to small.  Then I tried using a program to program any scaling i want; which really isn't perfect.  For example, foobar doesn't scale.  A few other program simply doesn't scale or it would scale, but the overhead writing on the tabs, the maximize/minimize and other stuff don't scale.  The problem literally doesn't exist on Windows.

Now, I don't mind simply booting onto windows just for games.  I also will need microsoft office products for work; though over time, I could get use to the open source one on linux, libre.

I can somewhat get use to the citrix issue; though when I really need something critical; i'll have no choice but to boot windows.

But currently, the display scaling issue is bugging me to no end.  It's like I'm fighting the operating system.  Constantly Zooming everything with low dpi to like 150, 160%; for example when surfing the internet, zooming the browser.  OR on Hidpi, I'm constantly minimzing stuff and the banners just take too much of my screen since they are so damn large.

Is there truly any Global (meaning affects EVERYTHING) scaling software/technique/ terminal entry available on elemetary OS.

Thanks.

Comment: You know HiDPI is the only thing keeping me from using Elementary OS. I am using a laptop with a native 3840x2160 and I need a scale of 1.5 HiDPI as 1 is too small and 2 is just overly large. Why there is a 3 OMG.. who knows.. anyhow.. Is there any chance if getting a 1.5 or does this cause issues with graphics?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  Following a little bit from https://askubuntu.com/questions/884249/how-to-generate-config-monitors-xml-file-from-a-script

1. 'Display Settings' and click 'Apply'.  This will create `~/.config/monitors.xml`
2. In the terminal `sudo nano ~/.config/monitors.xml`
3. Add or edit the following inside the `<logicalmonitor>` node.  So monitors > configuration > logicalmonitor
   `<scale>1</scale>` making sure that the scale is set to an appropriate scale for you
4. Restart

I want to say I tried the suggestions [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16458/juno-display-scaling-issues) at some point but I can't recall if it worked

YMMV